# В каких речевых ситуациях уместно использовать слово "дефиниция"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Дефиниция ― это, согласно словарю, краткое определение, но можно ли этими словами пользоваться как синонимами?

К примеру, в частном разговоре, в  том числе на форуме, мне оно кажется неуместным (хотя и на форумах это слово тоже иногда используется). Может быть, тема разговора должна быть особой, связанной с книжной философией.

Но использование "дефиниции" вместо "определения" без особой необходимости мне не нравится. Почему?  Возможно, книжная фонетика слова напрягает слух и кажется неприятной, а сам говорящий представляется лицом, подчеркивающим свою образованность. Это впечатление усиливается, если он при этом  явно ошибается в каких-то общеизвестных и несложных вещах.

В то же время я не уверена в своем оценке  ситуации. А как вы относитесь к слову "дефиниция"?

ДЕФИНИЦИЯ,  [лат. definitio] Книжн. Краткое определение какого-л. понятия, содержащее наиболее существенные его признаки.

Примеры:

1) **Дефиниция** нередко принимает случайные непосредственные свойства, вместо того чтобы достичь выведения их из конкретной всеобщности. [С. С. Неретина, А. П. Огурцов. Пути к универсалиям. Раздел IV. Универсалии как идеи: от номинализма к реализму (2006)]

2) ― Любая *дефиниция* страдает определенной невозможностью адекватно описать то, что она призвана описывать. [Андрей Геласимов. Рахиль (2004) // «Октябрь», 2003]

3) Очень просто! Ваша *дефиниция* «толерантности» ― теория. А мы живем в практике! [коллективный. Форум: Православие и «Русский марш» (2012)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я пару раз видел ситуацию, когда употребление слова "определение" сбивало спорящих с толку: один употреблял его в обсуждаемом значении, а другой видел отглагольное.

Ещё на форумах часто просят дать дефиниции, давая тем самым понять оппоненту, что продолжать обсуждение в стиле бессмысленного махания руками ("вон та штуковина, все и так знают, что это такое") не удастся. Это один из простых и распространённых способов поставить завравшегося собеседника на место.

Не припомню других случаев сетевого общения, в которых я счёл бы использование этого слова уместным. Книжный стиль осуждать не буду: слово разрешено и каждый вправе им пользоваться в меру своих предпочтений.

Comment: Может быть, в названных  случаях  сетевого общения книжно-научное слово приобретает иронический оттенок, как это бывает со словами высокого стиля? Неужели можно в разговоре вполне серьезно  спросить: "какую дефиницию имеет это слово?" вместо "как вы определяете это слово?"

Comment: @Ксения Бывает и так и этак. Люди, привыкшие к научной стилистике (преподаватели и учёные, например), свободно пользуются этим словом (иногда с более широким контекстом значений -- сказывается давление английского, на котором эти люди много общаются и пишут почти все свои статьи).